# saving onenote 2013 notebook as only one file only

Tags: iphone, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-office-2013

I am using onenote 2013 and when I create a notebook, if I have 60 tabs in it, it creates 60 seperate .one files.  This is a problem for me because to view the notebook on my iphone, I have to scroll through 60 different notebooks.  On my iphone, every .one file looks like a notebook, which it is not.  This worked fined with onenote 2010, but since MS changed the design with onenote 2013, this is a problem for onenote on my iphone.

Any idea's how I can save all my .one files into just one file?  Or using onenote 2013, to save my notebook as only .one file?

Answer (score 0):

You can save your notebook into a .onepkg file, however this method is the equivalent to an archive.

I do not believe you can have only one file for your entire notebook unless you group it.